# unrecognized objects using Facebook c# sdk samples

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm starting to use Facebook c# SDK. By starting with a sample provided on the source(CSASPNETWebsiteRegistrationForm) I added the references and using Facebook and Facebook.Web but sentences like FacebookApplication.Current.AppId are not recognized by Visual Studio.(not exist in the current context). Am I missing something?
Sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

You are missing references to Facebook.dll and Facebook.Web.dll. These are available in the source download in the bin folder.

Comment: Thank very much for the answer. I think I was using another version of the references.